# Do I need to Escape a Subquery?

Tags: mysql, code-injection

I have a SQL query that goes like this:

```
UPDATE User SET flag='Y' WHERE email=(SELECT email FROM Forum WHERE id='$id');
```

Because the **email address** can consist of single quotes and some special characters (s*a'{f`%$.=*+~&^#|g!/hd@[66.112.45.34] and vy."(),:;<>[]".VY."vy\\ \@\"vy".unal@str.exe.com are both valid email addresses), I am not sure whether it is necessary to do the subquery separately, escape the output, followed by using it in the main query.

What is your suggestion?

ADD NOTE: `$id` is a safe number.

Comment: When in doubt, escape it.  There's nothing to lose.

Comment: your query is ok.  no  need to escpe anything there.

Comment: @ Randy, can you explain why?

Comment: I would escape anything that is user input, so in this case escape $id.

Comment: @AllisonC: I would escape anything that is not specifically known to need no escaping, regardless if it comes directly from user input or not.

Comment: Because it's not leaving mysql - injection attacks happen where data crosses between different environments (not just [some language]/database but also some [lang]/javascript, [some lang]/[other lang],

Comment: @ symcbean, I think you give me a very clear idea.

Comment: Consider re-writing the query to use a join instead of a subquery. Something like this should be much faster: `UPDATE User, Forum SET User.flag='Y' WHERE User.email=Forum.email AND Forum.email = $id;`

Comment: @ Mike B, thanks! I think that is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape anything because there is a subquery, but of course you need to escape the `id` value to put it in the string.

If possible, you should use a parameterised query instead of concatenating the value into the string. Then you don't have to escape anything.

Comment: You didn't write the reason, symcbean wrote down the reason. Is he correct?

Comment: @BenHuh: His explanation covers the most common cases, but it's not correct. Just because the data doesn't leave the database doesn't automatically mean that it doesn't need to be escaped. If you create a query dynamically in the database, any values that you put in the query still needs to be escaped.

Comment: then what do you mean by "You don't need to escape anything because there is a subquery"? Sorry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: @BenHuh: The result of the subquery is a string value that is used directly as a value, it's not used as a string literal in a string that is parsed as a new query.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to escape anything in your subquery.  However, whatever query inserts email originally to your database needs to escape that field.  Escaping should take please when you add or modify the `email` field.

Comment: You don't escape a value because it's going to be stored in the field, you escape the value to use it in the query. How you use the value in the query is irrelevant.

Comment: @Guffa I was more making the point that the value of the email field should already be clean by the time they are using it in the sub-query, and that the query is question doesn't have any user generated data being injected directly into it.

Comment: @ danielrsmith, I think there is a misconception that the data is clean. The escaping is for the query itself, not the data.

Answer (score 1):

The information needed to answer is: "Where does $id come from?"

If it can be modified externally it needs to be quoted. If it is for example passed as an GET argument `http://www.foo.com/foo.php?id=222` it needs to be quoted (same for POST).

With a little bit of quotation the parameter can close the subquery and every query could be executed, e. g., by providing `"'); DELETE * FROM User; --`" as a value for `$id`:

```
UPDATE User SET flag='Y' WHERE email=(SELECT email FROM Forum WHERE id=''); 
DELETE * FROM User; --');
```

Comment: My question has nothing to do with `$id` but rather the `email` which is queried from the table `Forum` and subsequently applied again in the main query. You can assume that `$id` is a safe number.

Comment: Well, then you don't have to. Replacec $Id by "query condition" in my question above. If it's pure internal data, then you don't have to. Or would you escape while concatinating strings in a select clause?